# How do I detect keyboard hit without echoing the characters that user typed on Linux with C?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to detect keyboard hit without echoing the character that user types on Linux with C, here are the functions.

```
void initTermios()
{
  tcgetattr(0, &old);              /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
  current = old;                   /* make new settings same as old settings */
  current.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;      /* disable buffered i/o */
  current.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;        /* set no echo mode */
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &current); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios()
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

/* Read 1 character without echo */
char _getch()
{
  char ch;
  initTermios();
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}

int _kbhit()
{
  int byteswaiting;
  initTermios();
  ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &byteswaiting);
  resetTermios();
  return byteswaiting;
}
```

I tested the `_getch()` function with the following code.

```
int main(void)
{
  char ch = _getch();
  printf("%d", ch);
  return 0;
}
```

It works as expected, gets the character without echoing it.

However, when I put `_getch()` and `_kbhit()` together, the program echos the character I typed,

```
int main()
{
  char ch;
  while (1)
  {
    if (_kbhit()>0)
    {
      ch = _getch();
      printf("\n%d\n", ch);
    }
    printf(" ");
    fflush(stdout);
    usleep(200000);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How do I fix the bug?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working, but you probably don't want to muck with the termios modes so often.  Try calling your `initTermios` function once at the top of `main()`, and `resetTermios` once at the end, and you should be fine.  (You don't end up with "drop-in" replacements for `kbhit` and `getch` that way, but I'm not at all sure that drop-in replacements are possible under Unix/Linux.)

Comment: Follow Steve's suggestion about doing `initTermios/resetTermios` _once_ at start/end. Otherwise, you have a race condition and the kernel TTY layer might do the echo because it isn't in raw mode when the user types a key. The `kbhit` can be implemented with a `select` call and/or `ioctl` call with `FIONREAD`, followed by a `read` call. Note that you _can't_ use `getchar` which uses the `stdio` _stream_. You have to do this with a `read` syscall instead. When you set "raw" TTY mode with `termios`, you can no longer use `stdio` calls.

Comment: @CraigEstey Good call on the race condition.  But I'm pretty sure I've used `getchar` in cbreak and raw mode.  What's the problem?  Who says you can't do this?